# Uniform convergence in $L^p$-spaces

Tags: convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

Let $f\in L^p(0,\infty)$, $p>1$. Show that $\int_0^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin xy}{x} dx$ converges uniformly in $y$ in every finite interval. Show also that $|g(t+y)-g(y)|\leqslant M|t|^{\frac{1}{p}}$. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried with Holder's inequality (because of $f\in L^p(0,\infty)$).

Comment: Then I tried to put $t=x y$, but I don't know how should I conclude   that the convergence is uniform. Any help is welcome...

Answer (score 3):

For the integral $\int_0^1 f(x)\frac{\sin xy}{x}\,dx$, use $|\sin xy|\le xy$, canceling $x$ in the denominator.

For the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x)\frac{\sin xy}{x}\,dx$, use $|\sin xy|\le 1$ and then Hölder's   inequality: 
$$
\int_1^\infty f(x)\frac{1}{x}\,dy \le  \|f\|_{L^p} \left(\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^q}\,dx\right)^{1/q}
$$
where $q$ is the conjugate exponent.

For the last part, estimate $\left|\sin [x(y+t)]-\sin xy\right|$ by $\min(tx,2)$. Using Hölder's   inequality again, you end up estimating the $L^q$ norm of $\min(tx,2)/x$. This is of order $t^{1/p}$.